# change in form-checkout.php by using code in functions.php

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Specific, how do i remove "Your order" or the full function? By using a code snippet in functions.php (child-theme)

It can be found by:

```
<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

in form-checkout.php.

I would prefer some code instead of coping the file to child-theme and alter the file.

Comment: you can try with CSS `#order_review_heading { display : none; }`

Comment: You are right, add .woocommerce-checkout #order_review_heading { display:none; } to the style.css also does it! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By injecting CSS (not optimal):

```
function remove_message_text() {
      echo '<style type="text/css">#order_review_heading { display: none; } </style>'; // Remove original text "Your Order"
      }
      add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'remove_message_text');
```